# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am using https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form example index-3.html, contact-3.php, contact-3.js. Getting error 'SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111). I tried 1) smtp port 465 with SMTPSecure ssl 2) smtp port 587 SMTPsecure tls 3) smtp port 25. But not able to send mail. Kindly suggest solution.

Comment: My suggested solution: move to an ISP that doesn't block outbound SMTP. The PHPMailer troubleshooting guide shows you how to diagnose this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) ERROR MESSAGE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918358/smtp-error-failed-to-connect-to-server-connection-refused-111-error-message)